# py.test xdist capture all output per process

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I want to use pytest-xdist for testing. I run tests in 3 processes, but my tests (and teardown) have stderr output and want to capture it. If I use:

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    captured_stderr = item.outerr[1]
    if captured_stderr:
        with open("captured_" + str(os.getpid()), "a") as f:
            f.write(captured_stderr)
```

then in captured_* file there is an output, but I want it also have pytest diagnostic messages (because I want to understand later what test this output belongs to), such as `[gw0] PASSED file:line test_something`. How can I save console output to file but split it by each process?